# Split the bits!

Tags: code-golf, number-theory, integer-partitions

We define \$V(x)\$ as the list of distinct powers of \$2\$ that sum to \$x\$. For instance, \$V(35)=[32,2,1]\$.

By convention, powers are sorted here from highest to lowest. But it does not affect the logic of the challenge, nor the expected solutions.

### Task

Given a [semiprime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiprime) \$N\$, replace each term in \$V(N)\$ with another list of powers of \$2\$ that sum to this term, in such a way that the union of all resulting sub-lists is an exact cover of the matrix \$M\$ defined as:

$$M_{i,j}=V(P)_i \times V(Q)_j$$

where \$P\$ and \$Q\$ are the prime factors of \$N\$.

This is much easier to understand with some examples.

### Example #1

For \$N=21\$, we have:

- \$V(N)=[16,4,1]\$
- \$P=7\$ and \$V(P)=[4,2,1]\$
- \$Q=3\$ and \$V(Q)=[2,1]\$
- \$M=\pmatrix{8&4&2\\4&2&1}\$

To turn \$V(N)\$ into an exact cover of \$M\$, we may split \$16\$ into \$8+4+4\$ and \$4\$ into \$2+2\$, while \$1\$ is left unchanged. So a possible output is:

$$[ [ 8, 4, 4 ], [ 2, 2 ], [ 1 ] ]$$

Another valid output is:

$$[ [ 8, 4, 2, 2 ], [ 4 ], [ 1 ] ]$$

### Example #2

For \$N=851\$, we have:

- \$V(N)=[512,256,64,16,2,1]\$
- \$P=37\$ and \$V(P)=[32,4,1]\$
- \$Q=23\$ and \$V(Q)=[16,4,2,1]\$
- \$M=\pmatrix{512&64&16\\128&16&4\\64&8&2\\32&4&1}\$

A possible output is:

$$[ [ 512 ], [ 128, 64, 64 ], [ 32, 16, 16 ], [ 8, 4, 4 ], [ 2 ], [ 1 ] ]$$

### Rules

- Because factorizing \$N\$ is not the main part of the challenge, you may alternately take \$P\$ and \$Q\$ as input.
- When several possible solutions exist, you may either return just one of them or all of them.
- You may alternately return the exponents of the powers (e.g. \$[[3,2,2],[1,1],[0]]\$ instead of \$[[8,4,4],[2,2],[1]]\$).
- The order of the sub-lists doesn't matter, nor does the order of the terms in each sub-list.
- For some semiprimes, you won't have to split any term because \$V(N)\$ already is a perfect cover of \$M\$ (see [A235040](https://oeis.org/A235040)). But you still have to return a list of (singleton) lists such as \$[[8],[4],[2],[1]]\$ for \$N=15\$.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf)!

#### Test cases

```
 Input | Possible output
-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 9     | [ [ 4, 2, 2 ], [ 1 ] ]
 15    | [ [ 8 ], [ 4 ], [ 2 ], [ 1 ] ]
 21    | [ [ 8, 4, 4 ], [ 2, 2 ], [ 1 ] ]
 51    | [ [ 32 ], [ 16 ], [ 2 ], [ 1 ] ]
 129   | [ [ 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 2 ], [ 1 ] ]
 159   | [ [ 64, 32, 32 ], [ 16 ], [ 8 ], [ 4 ], [ 2 ], [ 1 ] ]
 161   | [ [ 64, 32, 16, 16 ], [ 8, 8, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2 ], [ 1 ] ]
 201   | [ [ 128 ], [ 64 ], [ 4, 2, 2 ], [ 1 ] ]
 403   | [ [ 128, 64, 64 ], [ 32, 32, 16, 16, 16, 8, 8 ], [ 8, 4, 4 ], [ 2 ], [ 1 ] ]
 851   | [ [ 512 ], [ 128, 64, 64 ], [ 32, 16, 16 ], [ 8, 4, 4 ], [ 2 ], [ 1 ] ]
 2307  | [ [ 1024, 512, 512 ], [ 256 ], [ 2 ], [ 1 ] ]
```

Comment: can we take P and Q instead of N?

Comment: @ngn I'm going to say yes, because factorizing N is not the main part of the challenge.

Comment: May we return the output flattened?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer ... The output flattened is just a partition of the input (1+2+2+4=9, for example). I don't think it should be allowed

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer I don't think it could be unambiguous this way, as the last term of a sub-list may be the same as the first term of the next one.

Comment: @Arnauld It will surely not be, I just asked if it's allowed.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer So, no it's not.

Answer (score 4):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://gitlab.com/n9n/k), <s>66</s> 63 bytes

```
{(&1,-1_~^(+\*|a)?+\b)_b:b@>b:,/*/:/2#a:{|*/'(&|2\x)#'2}'x,*/x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVBLb4JAEL73V0yikV1cQ/fBQneStv9DfMCBptHYxHjAAP51Oguxdj3M5XvOzGF1@joNQ@1atpBiJXe3LVsWcVfyj2VR8V3lqs/3yokkTlyiZqVruziJ2KJTRcNnkeqjRsRJ0w8X187X19vZ1dDg/ueAbF@X30ds8IpnvulfLmsNGgCZAQUKheSbEUs9JnIUBsU/OPNwDgYMBnKZebn2iA0MRhNhDWgF0oJ3hjUP@m5@6sxABREkyccc85xlxx2kogBrMCAlHSmREQcUROzYN8VNe@U4XfUoplqdUWAqFQbG@xKhnH5j36jiVRkgix9i079vDL8)

accepts (P;Q) instead of N

algorithm:

- compute A as the partial sums of V(P*Q)
- multiply each V(P) with each V(Q), sort the products in descending order (let's call that R), and compute their partial sums B
- find the positions of those elements in B that also occur in A; cut R right after those positions

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 24 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
BṚT’2*
Ç€×þ/FṢŒṖ§⁼Ç}ɗƇPḢ
```

A monadic link accepting a list of two integers `[P, Q]` which yields one possible list of lists as described in the question.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AUcAuP9qZWxsef//QuG5mlTigJkyKgrDh@KCrMOXw74vRuG5osWS4bmWwqfigbzDh33Jl8aHUOG4ov/Dh8WS4bmY//9bMTMsIDMxXQ)** (footer prints a string representation to show the list as it really is)

Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/p4c5ZIY8aZhppcR1uf9S05vD0w/v03R7uXHR00sOd0w4tf9S453B77cnpx9oDHu5Y9P9wW9rhdqCWUJD0jIc712Y9apijoGun8Khhrmbk//@WOgqGpjoKRoY6CqZAbGgEFgARZkCukQGQMDEw1lGwAMkaGRuYAwA) (taking a list of N and reordering results to be like those in the question)

#### How?

We may always slice up the elements of \$M\$ from lowest up, greedily (either there is a \$1\$ in \$M\$ or we had an input of \$4\$, when \$M=[[4]]\$) in order to find a solution.

<sup>Note: the code collects all (one!) such solutions in a list and then takes the head (only) result - i.e. the final head is necessary as the partitions are not of all possible orderings.</sup>

```
BṚT’2* - Link 1, powers of 2 that sum to N: integer, N    e.g. 105
B      - binary                                                [1,1,0,1,0,0,1]
 Ṛ     - reverse                                               [1,0,0,1,0,1,1]
  T    - truthy indices                                        [1,4,6,7]
   ’   - decrement                                             [0,3,5,6]
    2  - literal two                                           2
     * - exponentiate                                          [1,8,32,64]

Ç€×þ/FṢŒṖ§⁼Ç}ɗƇPḢ - Main Link: list of two integers, [P,Q]
Ç€                - call last Link (1) as a monad for €ach
    /             - reduce with:
   þ              -   table with:
  ×               -     multiplication
     F            - flatten
      Ṣ           - sort
       ŒṖ         - all partitions
              Ƈ   - filter keep if:
             ɗ    -   last three links as a dyad:
         §        -     sum each
            }     -     use right...
               P  -       ...value: product (i.e. P×Q)
           Ç      -       ...do: call last Link (1) as a monad
          ⁼       -     equal? (non-vectorising so "all equal?")
                Ḣ - head
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>261</s> <s>233</s> <s>232</s> 231 bytes

```python
g=lambda n,r=[],i=1:n and g(n/2,[i]*(n&1)+r,i*2)or r
def f(p,q):
 V=[[v]for v in g(p*q)];i=j=0
 for m in sorted(-a*b for a in g(p)for b in g(q)):
	v=V[i]
	while-m<v[j]:v[j:j+1]=[v[j]/2]*2
	i,j=[i+1,i,0,j+1][j+1<len(v)::2]
 return V
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NZBBcoMwDEXXcAqtGgzKJDZJmNK4x2Dj8YIMkJgBQ1xKp6enMqQb6f0v2bI1/k6PwYplucuu7G9VCRadVBqN5LmF0lZwj@xBoDI6juwbZ4lDEws2OHBhVTfQRCM@WR5CIZWadUOFGYylY2P8ZPrDyFYeQ/B@7/2vwU11Fe3L@Laa5auZeXHbxJPRhcEsC5oaBj8P09X7/jqrVucU8jbhWiovD0LHIgwMtlKZhKPBI/qqonDtahvNLM@FDsHV07ezUCx@Cj3Yz1FRiilDoHT2KdsUz/7d05rPr64Mxea/QKUIl0wTcKKUexKeVo8gu7xrTf8YnbET0DZwJ3e4rovoc4fb6pY/)

1 byte from [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king); and another 1 byte due to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen).

Takes as input `p,q`. Pursues the greedy algorithm.

Comment: `-k-1` can be `~k`.

Comment: The `i,j` assignment can be `i,j=[i+1,i,0,j+1][j+1<len(v)::2]` for -1 byte

Comment: @Jo King: Hahaha! That is twisted!

Comment: `while v[j]>-m` can be `while-m<v[j]`

Comment: @Kevin Cruijssen: Yes, indeed. Thx!

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 41 bytes

```
Œṗl2ĊƑ$Ƈ
PÇIP$ƇṪÇ€Œpµ³ÇIP$ƇṪƊ€ŒpZPṢ⁼FṢ$µƇ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opIc7p@cYHek6NlHlWDtXwOF2zwAg4@HOVYfbHzWtOTqp4NDWQ5sRose6IKJRAQ93LnrUuMcNSKkc2nqs/f/hdpBZM/7/jzbWMY8FAA)

Should probably be much shorter (some parts feel very repetitive; especially `ÇIP$Ƈ`, but I don't know how to golf it). Explanation to come after further golfing. Returns all possible solutions in case multiple exist and takes input as \$[P, Q]\$.

Comment: Not that it is a problem, but it's not exactly fast, is it? :)

Comment: @Arnauld It uses roughly 3 integer partition functions in a single run :) Of course it is not too fast

Comment: Now waiting to be outgolfed. I think it's possible in sub-35/30, but I don't think I'll be able to do anything much shorter

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 34 bytes

```
BṚT’2*
PÇŒṗæḟ2⁼ƊƇ€ŒpẎṢ⁼Ṣ}ʋƇÇ€×þ/ẎƊ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/p4c5ZIY8aZhppcQUcbj866eHO6YeXPdwx3@hR455jXcfaHzWtOTqp4OGuvoc7FwGFgGTtqe5j7YdBEoenH96nD5Q61vX/cFva4XZ3oFjWo8Z9h7Yd2vb/v5EhAA)

Input format: `[P, Q]` (the TIO link above doesn't accept this, but a single number instead, to aid with the test cases).

Output format: List of all solutions (shown as grid representation of 3D list over TIO).

Speed: Turtle.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 27 bytes

Inspired by [Jonathan Allan's crushing of my Jelly solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/170102/59487). Takes \$N\$ as input.

```
L^2x1jb2;hfqyQsMT./S*M*FyMP
```

[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=L%5E2x1jb2%3BhfqyQsMT.%2FS%2aM%2aFyMP&input=21&debug=0)

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, <s>281</s> 195 bytes

```
import Data.List
r=reverse.sort
n#0=[]
n#x=[id,(n:)]!!mod x 2$(n*2)#div x 2
m!0=[]
m!x=m!!0:tail m!(x-m!!0)
m%[]=[]
m%n=m!head n:drop(length$m!head n)m%tail n
p&q=r[x*y|x<-1#p,y<-1#q]%r(1#(p*q))
```

Comment: Here are some tips: Defining operators instead of binary functions is cheaper, rearranging guards and pattern-matching can save you `(==)`, use `1>0` instead of `True` and don't use `where`. Also `n'` can be shortened.. With this you can save 72 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcxNCoMwEAXgvacYsUoirfizs7WrLnsDcREw1NBkjDGUFLy7jUILXT3me48Z2PzkUq6rUHo0Fm7MsuwuZhuYxvAXNzPPZl8EGLlFjT04KK95gzXBtKRRL16bLM7bvxRe2i5QodtLFYZ5bZmQoELiTttJf5u47XyeVYx@N3DWA9a9GTWRHB92OHyRqnh/gYFOpsa0Ln0v7nIqIn18bzF1sSFFRHQ6UboqJhAa0EaghQNUSbV@AA "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: Btw. you should check out the [Haskell tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/19255/tips-for-golfing-in-haskell) section if you havent.

Comment: I had a look at the guard situation again, another 13 bytes off: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYvLCoMwFET3@Yob1JJIW/rYSbPrsn8gLgIJNdR7jTFIhP67VaGr4cycafX4sV23LA59HyI8ddTnlxsjCyrYyYbRnsd1YJRdVN2skVTtzFFQJRvOsTeQ4JYLKm8yM27aiCHfXeRJIeeXKmrXAXKRThtKhkXd7EJBq9BabYAqE3ovOkvv2Ob/UmKxf4n5w6BCncr5mx6na@aP8xZDUwRxzYQvBykX1I5AgQ@OIuRwP9yXHw "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: @OMᗺ, thank you. I'm new to haskell, so this looks for me as magic tricks

Comment: No  worries :) In case you have questions, feel free to ask in [Of Monads and Men](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66515/of-monads-and-men).